# What's the difference between Good and Light in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As a Catholic, I'm a little Manichean-heresy sensitive, so when I heard Princes Leia say in Ep.7 :

> There is still light in him, in reference to her son

I got a little nervous. Because Luke says to Leia in Ep.6:

> There is still good in him, in reference to his father

So what happened in the intervening 30 years that turned "good" to "light"?

Or are they the same thing, according to the ways of the force (albeit "from a certain point of view")?

Comment: I'm guessing that after 30 years of putting up with Luke yapping on about the Light side of the Force, she's started to use his jargon.

Comment: Good and evil are abstracts, light and dark are absolute?

Comment: @Politank-Z, black and white are absolute. Light and dark are still mostly relative. Can someone be "lighter" than someone else who could also be described as light?

Comment: @DangerZone When speaking of the electromagnetic spectrum, light and dark are relative. When speaking of The Force, not so much.

Comment: @Politank-Z, not to argue, but that's still what I was getting at. Would a Jedi with even a tiny amount of anger/hatred come off as slightly darker compared to someone more pure? I would think so... But maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Politank-Z Good and evil are abstract?

Comment: @MattGutting Indeed, they are human-constructed ideas to describe the quality of actions.

Comment: @Politank-Z Not everyone agrees with that...but I'll leave it there.

Comment: @DangerZone The totality of a person, I suppose, could be seen as lighter or darker, but I don't think The Force itself has such gradations.

Comment: The "Good" side is the side you're on. The "Light" side is the specific way of accessing/connecting with the Force. People on the Light Side happen to consider themselves Good, but unsurprisingly, aren't unique in that assessment.